# VB Spell Check Code issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have managed to assemble the following code for spell checking a locked document but just cant quit get it to work. I would like it to look at only unlocked cells but still use the 'CommandBars("Tools").Controls("Spelling...").Execute' function. Any ideas would be great. TIA

```
Sub SelectUnlockedCells_Spellcheck()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=""

    Dim WorkRange As Range

    Dim FoundCells As Range

    Dim Cell As Range

    Set WorkRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    For Each Cell In WorkRange

        If Cell.Locked = False Then

            If FoundCells Is Nothing Then

                Set FoundCells = Cell

            Else

                Set FoundCells = Union(FoundCells, Cell)

            End If

        End If

    Next Cell

    If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "All cells are locked."

    Else

        FoundCells.CheckSpelling CommandBars("Tools").Controls("Spelling...").Execute

    End If

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=""

End Sub
```

Comment: if this is excel you might want to add the appropriate tags

Comment: My problem is trying to make this work;

 "FoundCells.CheckSpelling CommandBars("Tools").Controls("Spelling...").Execute"

Either this, “CheckSpelling CommandBars("Tools").Controls("Spelling...").Execute”
Or this “FoundCells.CheckSpelling CustomDictionary:="CUSTOM.DIC", _
IgnoreUppercase:=False, AlwaysSuggest:=True, SpellLang:=3081
“
But I need the function of both to work. Thanks again.

Comment: Let me rephrase: VB.NET is not vba.  You'll get better help with the correct tags.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this code

```
FoundCells.CheckSpelling CommandBars("Tools").Controls("Spelling...").Execute
```

But the VBA help doesn't show any such parameters. Try using just this:

```
FoundCells.CheckSpelling
```